# What's the best practice to choose in which type I should parse xml string?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have http-server, it can accept several different xml messages (strings).
Each message should be deserialized to the specific type object. What's the best practice to choose which type I should use for the message? At the moment I check the root node of the message and then choose type.

Comment: it depends on your application. what is wrong with your current approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a common base class and tell the xml deserializer (.NET) the derived types that it can use.
See:

```
 XmlSerializer Constructor (Type type, Type[] extraTypes)
```

MSDN: "You can also use the extraTypes parameter to specify types derived from a base class. For example, suppose a base class named Phone exists, and a class named InternationalPhone derives from it. Use the extraTypes parameter to specify the derived type as well."